# How is a blind character working at film developer lab?

Tags: plot-explanation, manhunter

In Manhunter (1986), Reba McClane (a completely blind person) is found working at film lab.

I know blind people can have other heightened senses, but surely film lab workers really need sight to adjust saturation,brightness,contrast etc of a working film.

How is a blind character working at a film lab?

Comment: See [notch code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notch_code).

Comment: That is done *after* the film has been fully developed - and then it's not sensitive to light anymore.   Photo labs would probably use a machine - eg. you'd tape the undeveloped film to a plastic sheet (with holes in it) and put it into one end of the machine.   The card is gripped by a belt and drags the film through various baths.  When it comes out the other end, the film is developed.  Only moving the film from the camera, rolling it up, and putting it into a light-tight cylinder (before taping one end to the sheet) *must* be done in darkness.  Baths temps are regulated automatically.

Comment: What can I say, I worked 10 years at "One Hour Photo"-shop... took about 10 minutes to develop a C-41 color film - of course they already had a light-tight container, so you only had to fish out the end of the film, trim it with a special knife, and tape it to the sheet.  (For 6in professional film though, you'd had to put it in a light-proof cylinder.)  When the film came out, you put it into a special scanner and made paper prints - using another machine that carried sheets of photo-paper (automatically cut from a roll) through several baths.

Comment: I have seen stranger things....Colour blind people working as designers...

Comment: @JDługosz For a moment I thought that was going to be an article about [Markus Persson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markus_Persson).

Comment: @BaardKopperud «That is done after the film has been fully developed» what are you referring to with “that”?

Comment: @BaardKopperud sheet film like for a view camera or scientific instrument incorporating same will often be developed in *trays*, as well as the need to load the panels with film out of the bulk box.  Now I'm sure there were robots to handle sheets in an automated developer machine, but these people might have custom orders: which developer chemicals to use, what temperature, and times.  So small batch and no reuse of the developer.  The scene was *not* a one-hour photo.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro designers of *what* will make all the difference in how I read that.

Comment: @JDługosz multimedia designers

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### Reba works with highly sensitive infrared film.

> REBA: The 1000 C Infrared Sensitive Film must be handled in total darkness.      I keep the samples straight by touch code.
>
> <sup>[Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Manhunter.html)</sup>

The novel explains further.

> ...she outlined the mechanics of the development—chemicals, temperature and time, and storage procedures before and after filming.
>
> **Infrared-sensitive film must be handled in total darkness.** She had done all the dark room work, keeping the many samples straight by touch code and keeping a running record in the dark
>
> <sup>Red Dragon - Thomas Harris</sup>

Comment: Reminds me of a photography class with a lesson on using sheet film.  It was in **total darkness** and the teacher explained which way to orient the sheet. “how do you tell which side is the emulsion?” someone asked.  She responded “it’s the shiney side!” which drew laughter from everyone.  Sheets are in fact [coded with notches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notch_code), giving the specific product and allowing you to orient it.

Comment: Also relevant: blind people learn to read braille. Given their experience reading textured surfaces, reading the touch codes comes more naturally to a blind person than a [sighted] person.

Comment: @JDługosz  LOL!  But seriously, you can easily feel which side is which - which one got the emulsion.

Comment: @BaardKopperud it depends on the film whether the sides feel different at all, you can never tell with cotton gloves, and you **never want to touch it** anyway.  If you must feel it, you've just left a thumbprint on your image.

Comment: I used to work in a hospital, and many of the X-ray film techs were blind. It was very common in the days before digital imaging.

Comment: @JDługosz but you are usually developping the imge on slightly larger paper than the resulting image and then you cut it out :)

Comment: @Crowley I never referred to *paper* anywhere.  I'm talking about 4×6 (in my case) *film sheets*.  They are  loaded into camera backs and exposed to make negatives.

Comment: @JDługosz When processing films you don't care where the emulsion is - you load it into a reel and put in the the tank. The rest is done with dry film and you don't care where the emulsion is either. the only thing, where you care which side holds the emulsion is the photo paper.

Comment: @Crowley when loading sheet film into [holders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_holder#Sheet_film_holders) (camera backs), you definitively want it facing the right way.  Likewise when setting up for contact prints, etc.  I think you don't know [how a view camera is operated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_camera#Operation).

Comment: @JDługosz I thought you were talking about "modern" SLRs like Canon A1 or Hasselblad 500 C.

Comment: @Crowley How does “sheet film” relate to SLRs that use rolled film stock?

Answer (score 17):

The point here is that she is working with infra-red film which is sensitive to any light therefore anyone developing it needs to work in total darkness so being blind is no disadvantage plus someone who is blind is actually much more used to working without being able to see so a blind person is actually at an advantage in this job.

Note also that the job is processing the negatives which is pretty much a purely technical operation as opposed to actually printing copies onto photographic paper which is a bit of a different thing.

Answer (score 7):

After many years working in the darkroom, mostly processing negatives, I noticed something.

Not only do I do this in complete darkness with no issues. I realised that, probably already for several years, I even close my eyes.
This way I "see" the film better :-)

And the other trick btw, to find the emulsion side is, to carefully take one corner between your - dry - lips.

The side that sticks is the emulsion.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the wet process. The development of film is prepared in complete darkness - you have to take the film out of light-tight cassette and put it in light-tight canister - and it is done in light-tight canisters. There is absolutely no way how to adjust the process according to actual state of the film.

You put the film in, close it, pour one chemical in , wait, pour chemical out, pour another in etc. Finally you get the result.

The only thing that blind person cannot do is the final assessment of the result. And developed film can wait a long time for someone to see it.
During other steps, blind people have significant advantage - they do not need any light, their other senses are boosted and they do not need hand-eye coordination to do anything.

The more the film is sensitive, the fewer light is allowed to help the operator to coordinate their hands. Blind people do not need any light.

The only steps you actually need to see anything is evaluation of the negative whether it was processed right then you can start developing the positive - the actual image. Here you have to focus the projection and you can alter the brightness etc.